# Php session in two php files

Tags: php, html

```
if(empty($prvi)&& empty($drugi)&&empty($treci)&&empty($cetvrti)){
             $upit1 = "INSERT INTO korisnici (ime, prezime, email, sifra, psifra, zanimanje, brojracuna, mesec, godina, banka) VALUES ('$ime','$prezime','$email','$sifra','$psifra','$zanimanje','$kartica','$mesec','$godina','$banka')";
             $rez = mysqli_query($conn, $upit1);

             $_SESSION['id'] = $email;
```

this is first.php

in secound.php i want to echo session['id']

In `first.php` I have `session_start();` and `$_SESSION['id'] = $email;`

`$email` is input tag.

How can I echo session in `secound.php`? I have `session_start();` too.

`first.php` and `secound.php` are in the same folder.

Comment: `echo $_SESSION['id'];`? Did you try that on `secound.php`?

Comment: yes i did, but nothing

Comment: Then you need to post actual code relating to the issue at hand.

Comment: Do you see the session cookie in the browser?

Comment: i deleted all cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have session_start(); on the first and you store the $_SESSION you just need to open session like you said and do something like

```
session_start();
$test = $_SESSION['id'];
echo $test;
```

if it doesn't work show some code.

Example First Page:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
//some mysql inserts ? 
if (sql worked) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['id'] = $email;
  header("Location:secound.php");
}
```

Second

```
session_start();
$store = $_SESSION['id'];
echo $store;
```

Comment: i did what you said, but nothing. i have Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\Seminarski\index_profil.php on line 7   line 7 is $store = $_SESSION['id'];

Comment: that's weird, you need to show more code can u put like the full of the first and second? because the simple example should work

Comment: and where is the $email is coming from?

Comment: it's working now. thank you very much. i don't know what happend, i moved session_start before $_SESSION['id'] = $email

Comment: yeah you need to put the session before using session vars , no problem have a nice day